# How to avoid .getSelectedFile() premature selection?

Tags: java, database, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser

It appears that the .getSelectedFile() functions will still choose a folder from a file chooser even after choosing the cancel option. Is there a different function? Like getOpenedFolder(), maybe? I would appreciate any help. Here is my code:

```
        boolean flag = false;
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:/Users/michaelartichoke/Desktop"));
        fc.setDialogTitle("PDF Manager");
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        
        chosenfolder = fc.getSelectedFile();
        try{
            folderpath = chosenfolder.getAbsolutePath();
            flag = true;
        } catch(Exception e){
            //
        }
        
        if(flag!=false){
            selecting();
        }
```

FYI, selecting() is the command that creates the database.

Comment: There is a `getCurrentDirectory()` method in JFileChooser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the result that `showOpenDialog()` returned to see if the user chose "Open":

```
int res = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
if (res==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    // User picked 'Open"
    chosenfolder = fc.getSelectedFile();
    // ...
}
```